# Simple ASPX cannot bind to vb.net codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this aspx page in my vs 2013 solution:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="PayPalTester._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Source Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my codebehind:

```
Namespace PayPalTester
    Partial Public Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub btnRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

When I try to compile I always get the error `Could not load type 'PayPalTester._Default'.`

If I remove `Inherits="PayPalTester._Default"` then I don't get that error anymore, but suddenly I get the new error `'btnRun_Click' is not a member of 'ASP.default_aspx'`.

These are such simple pages...I normally use c#, but have to use vb.net for this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project was setup as a Web Site project, but your page is configured as a Web Application project. Change your page declaration at the top of your markup from:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" 
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="PayPalTester._Default" %>
```

to:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" 
    Codefile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="PayPalTester._Default" %>
```

This MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx) compares the two.

Comment: Ok, then, At the top of your ASPX, change the 'Codebehind' attribute to 'CodeFile'.  I'm taking stabs, really... I'm not exactly sure which it is, but I've run into this before also.

Comment: This fixed everything: `<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codefile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="PayPalTester._Default" %>` -- if you'll change your answer to this, I'll accept it.